Firebase Robo test fails to sign in with Google SignIn
I am trying to test my Android apk in Firebase with a simple Robo test.
My app has a signIn activity as the landing page, where I have a Google Sign In option. I have already run multiple Robo tests, but every single time Robo gets stuck in the Google Sign In. What Robo does is the following:

It clicks on the "Sign In with Google" button.

The Google Sign In intent opens.

Robo clicks on the "Continue" button (see screenshot #1)

And here Robo gets stuck: instead of clicking on the "Continue as Nuage" button, it clicks repeteadly on the "LJDTQMQJEL2JPBVNOICIONGMX4-01@cloudtestlabaccounts.com" button (see screenshot #2) (it clicks the "Nuage laboratoire" account).


Here are both screenshots:
Screenshot #1
Screenshot #2
And here it is the history of Robo's actions, the loop is repeated for the whole duration of the test.
0:35
"Continue" has been pressed
continue_button
0:39
Pressed "LJDTQMQJEL2JPBVNOICIONGMX4-01@cloudtestlabaccounts.com"
account_name
0:40
Robo script terminated
0:41
Response was awaited
0:46
Pressed "LJDTQMQJEL2JPBVNOICIONGMX4-01@cloudtestlabaccounts.com"
account_name
0:48
Robo script completed
0:48
Response was awaited
0:54
Pressed "LJDTQMQJEL2JPBVNOICIONGMX4-01@cloudtestlabaccounts.com"
account_name
0:55
Robo script completed
0:56
Response was awaited
1:01
Pressed "LJDTQMQJEL2JPBVNOICIONGMX4-01@cloudtestlabaccounts.com"
account_name
1:03
Robo script finished"

Does anyone know why this happens and how can I fix it ? I cannot test the app if Robo does not manage to sign in...
Thanks you,
I tried running a Robo test, but Robo fails to finish the Google Sign In.
